# Pandas Can't Filter by Column Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get only those rows in a dataframe where a particular coulmn value is less than some upper bound.

I used to do this:

```
final_data[final_data['Time']<30.000000]
```

It gives me the error:

```
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match
```

I again tried with:

```
final_data.loc[:,final_data['Time']<30.000000]
```

and I get:

```
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match
```

How can I implement the filter in pandas based on column value?

Comment: Can you give an example of the input data?

Comment: Not sure about the error code tbh since, as jezrael pointed out, it shoul work. One thing I thought of is the use of "," an "." with numbers as separator, maybe that could make a difference (although it should't in this case - but just to throw it out there),

Comment: also, you may want to check this one too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas?rq=1

Comment: I don't know who upvoted this question but this is a typical one I would downvote for the lack of a data sample. Please  try to provide one in the future using `print(df.head(5).to_dict())` for instance.

Comment: @AntonvBR its a normal dataframe... should have put a datframe sample though..but this question just blocked me for two days..:( don't downvote..several people facing the same issue will benefit..whats wrong..alternative approaches solved the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion first solution should working perfectly in pandas `0.23.0`.

Another solutions are convert column to numpy array for avoid alignment of indexes between mask and DataFrame:

```
final_data[final_data['Time'].values < 30.000000]

final_data.loc[:,final_data['ResponseSLATime'].values < 30.000000]
```

Or use `query`:

```
final_data.query('Time < 30.000000')
```

Comment: same error on the query command IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match

Comment: With `.values` ?

Comment: this final_data[final_data['Time'].values < 30.000000] works!! thanks

Comment: why did the values one work? is there some pandas or version specifi cissue regarding filtering?

Comment: Maybe yes, not sure. I have this problem in some oldier pandas versions only.